# Android service stopSelf(int)

Tags: android, android-service

Here is my code -

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        new ServiceThread(startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    class ServiceThread extends Thread {
        private int startId;

        ServiceThread(int startId) {
            this.startId = startId;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) Math.random());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            stopSelf(startId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

According to this link "[Stopping a service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping)", I can/should call stopSelf with received "startId".

> However, if your service handles multiple requests to onStartCommand()
>   concurrently, then you shouldn't stop the service when you're done
>   processing a start request, because you might have since received a
>   new start request (stopping at the end of the first request would
>   terminate the second one). To avoid this problem, you can use
>   stopSelf(int) to ensure that your request to stop the service is
>   always based on the most recent start request. That is, when you call
>   stopSelf(int), you pass the ID of the start request (the startId
>   delivered to onStartCommand()) to which your stop request corresponds.
>   Then if the service received a new start request before you were able
>   to call stopSelf(int), then the ID will not match and the service will
>   not stop.

My question is, what will happen, if I invoke stopSelf with last "startId", and still some earlier start is still not finished. In that case, the startId will match, and according to that document the service will die? All all other earlier "starts" will just be killed?

If the answer is "yes", then what is the best practice to achieve that the service will not be killed until all earlier start is not finished.

Comment: Is it bad or wasteful to only call `stopSelf` once instead of multiple times?  I mean the same Service instance will only exist once per app process...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just run into exactly the same problem yesterday. And I think I found answer in the javadoc of Service.stopSelfResult(int startId) method.

> If you may end up processing IDs out of order (such as by dispatching them on separate threads), then you are responsible for stopping them in the same order you received them.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to maintain a boolean hash map with the start ID as the key. Then in your worker threads, instead of calling `stopSelf(int)` call a custom method which does the following:

Set the hash map entry to `true` using the start ID as the key. Iterate through the keys in  ascending order and call `stopSelf(key)` until you encounter a `false` entry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subtle problem - I'm not sure any of the solutions above are adequate/efficient.  The solution I use is based on a class called `ThreadPoolService`, which extends `Service` and operates as follows:

- It defines `HashSet<Integer>` that stores the `startId` passed by `onStartCommand()`
- It defines an `int` field called `mLastStartId` that stores the most recent `startId` passed by `onStartCommand()`
- It defines an `ExecutorService` initialized by either `newCachedThreadPool()` or `newFixedThreadPool()`
- It defines a `beginIntentProcessing()` method that adds the `startId` parameter to the `HashSet` and records the latest `startId` in `mLastStartId`
- It defines an `endIntentProcessing()` method that removes the `startId` parameter from the `HashSet` and returns if the `HashSet` is non-empty.  If the `HashSet` is empty, however, it calls the `stopSelf()` method on the `Service` superclass, passing in the `mLastStartId`.

I've omitted some details of the solution, but it's efficient and solves the underlying problem described above.  I'll be covering this topic (and many others) in my upcoming MOOCs on Android concurrent programming, which are described at http://www.coursera.org/course/posaconcurrency and http://www.coursera.org/course/posacommunication.

Doug

Comment: I don't understand, what is the purpose of your `ExecutorService`?  Does it organize different threads you are instantiating in the Service.

Comment: Not a good approach. If you have to execute 5 tasks and the service got killed halfway, which is very possible on modern devices with very aggressive LMK (Low Memory Killer), and since you didn't call `stopSelfResult(startId)` after the task completes, the service will be restarted by the system and execute all tasks again instead of just the remaining ones. Ofc, we assume the `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` has been returned from `onStartCommand()`, which you almost always want.